# Inserting External, Reactive API Data into a Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, rest, http, meteor, meteor-collections

I have some **external data** I'm calling from an **API**. The data is WordPress posts objects I'm fetching via the [WordPress API](http://v2.wp-api.org/).

I'm using the [HTTP](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http) package and my code looks like this.

*server.js*

```
const articleIncoming = HTTP.call( 'GET', 'http://myUrl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', {}, function( error, articleIncoming ) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log( error );
  } else {
    console.log( articleIncoming );
 });
```

Where `articleComing` is the response. One WordPress **post** object looks like this in the console. This data updates with new posts on a regular basis and I would like the collection `Posts`, which I'm loading this data into, to reflect that.

[image]

Now that I have my data, I want to add these posts to a collection called `Posts` but I'm having difficulty.

*server.js*

```
const articleIncoming = HTTP.call( 'GET', 'http://myUrl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', {}, function( error, articleIncoming ) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log( error );
  } else {
    console.log( articleIncoming );
 });

 Meteor.methods({
  'Posts.insert'(articleIncoming) {
    return Posts.insert({
      articleIncoming,

    });
  },
});
```

- How can I save the **constantly updating** WordPress posts into the
  collection, in a way that **updates** when a new post is published in
  WordPress?
- Without post **duplication**

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Meteor methods definition with calling.

*Article fetch&save code:*

```js
HTTP.get('http://myUrl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', (error, articleIncoming) => {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log( error );
  } else {
    Meteor.call('Posts.insert', articleIncoming, (err, postId) => {
      if (err) {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }
});
```

*Somewhere else:*

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'Posts.insert'(articleIncoming) {
    // prevent duplications, based in article's `id` field
    const _id = `article_${articleIncoming.id}`;
    return Posts.upsert({ _id }, articleIncoming);
  },
});
```